# Storing setting passwords in the database securely

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have a `.NET Web API`/`MVC` application that allows users to update SMTP and Active Directory credentials which are stored in a `SQL Server` database.  I thought I could use [Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613194(v=vs.108).aspx) to secure these in the db tables but I don't think `Hashing` will work now.  There is no verification being done as with user passwords authentication where there is a entered password to compare against the Hash.  I know a good place to put these settings is in the `web.config` file but this application needs to be able to update these settings so I thought the db is the best place.

I am trying to find a way using `.NET` to store the passwords in the database encrypted so they can be read and converted to plain text as needed.  Maybe this can be done with `hashing` but I don't understand how it can be?

Comment: Hashing is not reversible. If you need to be able to get back the password in its original form, you will need to use a reversible encryption method such as 3DES or RijndaelManaged.

Comment: If you are updating credentials in another system, then why are you even storing them?  Why not just set the passwords in the target system?  Storing users passwords in a way that is reversible is against most best practices and is a security vulnerability.

Comment: @brianfeucht This application needs to know the credentials of the target systems to perform functions using those system (sending emails using SMTP, accessing groups and users in AD).  It's not updating the credentials in the other systems.

Comment: No, that is still not a good reason. Create a service account with the proper access to perform those actions.

Comment: @mason Can you provide more detail? I'm not sure what you mean. By service account do you mean, create an account which the application runs as? This application is requiring admin users to enter the service account (user/pass) for Active Directory and the SMTP Server. That's what I am storing in the database so the application can use those services when it needs to.  I would like to store these in the web.config but there might be multiple servers that change often so the database seems like a better place for admins to manage the configuration of this application.

Comment: What mason is suggesting is to create an account which your application will run as and then grant the permissions required for the application to run to that account.  Active Directory will even allow you to assign permissions to impersonate a user so you can do things on their behalf without needing a specific user's password.  Chances are if you are storing a user's password, there is a better way to accomplish what you are doing.

Comment: I understand now.  I just need to figure out how to do this with Active Directory and SMTP in .NET.  I want to make installation of this web application easy and allow configuration from in the app or through the installer if possible.